# insertBefore(), before() & Closest - inserting data where I need it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert some HTML before a divider `class="replydivider"` using insertBefore() but I can't get it to work. This is my code:

```
   <div class="col-sm-12 mb-2 replydivider">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-2 offset-1">
       <img src="/assets/uploads/user/<?=$_SESSION['userImage'];?>" class="border rounded-circle comment-user-img mr-3">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 rounded form-inline">
        <form method="POST" class="form-group reply-form">
          <input type="text" name="comment" class="form-control mr-2" placeholder="Reply here" required>
          <input type="hidden" name="postId" value="<?=$id?>">
          <input type ="hidden" name="replyId" value="<?=$row['commentId'];?>">
        <input type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-primary" value="Reply">
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

The issue I'm having is it has to be inserted before the div relative to the form that is submitted as there will be many replydividers and forms on the page.

I've tried the following and countless variations but can't get it to work:

```
$(this).closest('.replydivider').before(data);

$(this).closest('div').find(".replydivider").before(data);

$(this).closest('form').find(".replydivider").before(data);

$(data).insertBefore('.replydivider');
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

EDIT:

This is my jquery function:

```
$(function () {
  $('.reply-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: '/comment/addComment',
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function (data) {
              alert('test');
              var test = "<p>Sample data</p>";
              $(this).closest('.replydivider').before(test);
          }
        });
        $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text]").val("");
        });
    });
```

Interestingly, if I put the `$(this).closest('.replydivider').before(test);` line outside the ajax call it works, but not inside it. I put the alert there to test it was returning successful and it is.

Comment: The first should work. Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Without context, it's unclear what `this` references to in relation to the code you are using it in.

Comment: Apologies, $(this) is the form that is being submitted

Comment: The first works: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/evs74r8c/2/

Comment: Thank you. I have made an edit with more context. It works outside the ajax call, but not inside - despite it returning sucessful.

Comment: The value of `this` changes within a `function(){}`.  Either use an arrow function, or store the `this` in another variable outside the ajax call and use the other variable inside the success method, or put `context: this` as an option to the ajax call so jQuery will force the context to be what you expect it to be in the success callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> The `this` reference within all callbacks is the object in the context option passed to `$.ajax` in the settings; if context is not specified, this is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.

If you want `this` in the callbacks to be the element that received the event then set the context property of Ajax like:

```
.......
context:this,
success: function (data) {
.......
```

Comment: Thank you! I also found a solution using ```success: (data) =>```